# Can Cyvasse be considered a chess variant?

Tags: discussion

Cyvasse is a game played in G. R. R. Martin's ASOFAI, link [here](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Cyvasse). Martin stated that the game is a little bit like chess (He's USFC 1950 btw), but the question remains, if I ask a question on Cyvasse, does it go to scifi.se or chess.se?

Comment: To add something to this, questions on 3d chess have been asked : http://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/5397/about-the-3d-chess-they-play-on-star-trek

Answer (score 3):

In short, I'd say no.

I haven't looked at the rules in any particular detail, but it seems to be created as a chess-like game rather than as a modification of chess itself.

I think the problem with allowing it on chess.se would be that:
 - Conversation is likely to turn to its use in the fictional setting
 - It would make many more chess-like games open for discussion here. This could lead to a situation (admittedly an extreme case) where actual chess discussion is less common than other games.

I would suggest that Cyvasse be talked about on **boardgames.se** instead